# High Score issues

Tags: int, save

i'm trying to carry over my final/best score into a new script but for some reason its taking a 0 value.. debug.Log down the bottom of the screen registers my final/best score but my public ints up top are not recognizing them? i don't get whats going on..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreBoard : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject m_new;
    public Score m_score;
    public Score m_best;
    public int best;
    public int final;


    public GameObject m_spriteBronze;
    public GameObject m_spriteSilver;
    public GameObject m_spriteGold;

    public int m_bronze = 10;
    public int m_silver = 20;
    public int m_gold = 30;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    public int setScore(int score)
    {

        if(m_gold <= score)
        {
            m_spriteGold.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if(m_silver <= score)
        {
            m_spriteSilver.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if(m_bronze <= score)
        {
            m_spriteBronze.SetActive(true);
        }

        string key = "best";
        int best = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key);
        if(best < score)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, score);
            best = score;
            m_new.SetActive(true);
        }
        m_score.setScore (score);
        m_best.setScore (best);

        int final = (score);

        Debug.Log(final);

        return final;



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `setScore()`, you redeclare `best` and `final`, e.g. `int best = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key);`. The second declarations are shadowing the ones at the top, which remain at their default values of `0`. Remove the `int` before your assignment.

Comment: remove the int before best?? as in best = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key);?

Comment: Yes. Since it is already declared `public int best;` at the top, having the `int` inside `setScore()` basically creates a different variable with the same name, valid only inside `setScore()`.

Comment: i changed it and still a fail :(